# XSLT Javascript extension can not call Date().toISOString()

Tags: javascript, xslt, xslt-extension

I have been experimenting with using extensions in **Microsoft XSLT** (1.0). In the JavaScript function I am just trying to return the current ISO date and time. Sounds easy enough.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                           xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                           xmlns:util="urn:Utility" extension-element-prefixes="ms"
                            >
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0"/>
    <ms:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="util">
    function today()
    {
        var d = new Date();
        return d.toISOString();
    }
    </ms:script>
    <!-- =============================================================== -->
    <xsl:template match="Person">
       <xsl:value-of select="util:today()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you execute the above it returns "Function expected". According to the Microsoft documentation `toISOString` is supposed for the JavaScript `Date()` object. If I use `toGMTString()` it returns the GMT value. I really need the current date returned in ISO format.

Any ideas?

Comment: [`.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) is not supported in <=IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toISOString()` is not a property of [the original jScript Date object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd9w2te4%28v=vs.84%29).

It is supported in IE9+, and even there in [standards rendering mode only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff925953%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Try this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:util="urn:Utility" 
  extension-element-prefixes="ms"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" />

  <ms:script language="jscript" implements-prefix="util">
  <![CDATA[
  function isoDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getUTCDate())
           + 'T' 
           + pad(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())
           + '.000Z';
  }

  function pad(num) {
    return (num < 10) ? '0' + num : '' + num;
  }
  ]]>
  </ms:script>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="util:isoDate()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0%28v=vs.84%29 as the documentation of the JScript script engine used in IE <= 8 and used by MSXML in `ms:script` sections. The link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xby9ffhf.aspx points to the JScript.NET version of JScript, an ECMAScript implementation in the .NET framework.

Comment: @Martin Absolutely. My bad, link fixed in answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already coded something very similar to your example. It just seemed that something this standard would be part of the Date object.

Comment: @Scott This is part of the standard *now*. It's been introduced with ECMAScript 5. JScript predates ECMAScript 5 by a whole couple of years.